# Number Picker problems

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a number Picker to get a information from the user, but when I call the number picker in the XML, I can see only the EditText, and the buttons doesn't appear.

```
<NumberPicker android:id="@+id/reais_picker"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/type_spinner" 
    android:layout_below="@id/valor_text" />
```

Comment: Which Android API level you are using?

Comment: Here is nice tutorial about number picker with explanation. http://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the max and min values and see if it makes a difference.

```
setMaxValue (int maxValue)
setMinValue (int minValue)
```

EDIT: I would also suggest to test on a real device.